# Minimal Polynomial of $1+i$ over $\Bbb Q$

Tags: field-theory, extension-field, minimal-polynomials, splitting-field, gaussian-integers

What is minimal polynomial of $1+i$ over $\mathbb{Q}$?

My attempt:

Let $x=1+i$, hence $(x-1)^2= i^2 = -1$, which is not possible in $\mathbb{Q}$, hence squaring further we obtain the minimal polynomial as $ x^4-4x^3+4x^2-4$.

Doubt:

1. Is this a required polynomial?
2. Are the justifications for the steps enough? ( particularly where I have written that this is not possible in $\mathbb{Q}$ )

Comment: The fact that ... is impossible is irrelevant. To prove that it's the minimal polynomial, just show that $1+i$ is a root, and that it is minimal.

Comment: The minimal polynomial of $1+i$ is defined as the monic polynomial of least degree among all polynomials in $\mathbb{Q}[x]$ having $1+i$ as a root.

Comment: Clearly $1+i$ should have degree $2$ over $\mathbb Q$, not degree $4$.

Comment: @Trebor I felt that how square can be -ve, $(x-1)^2= -1$ in set of rationals

Comment: @Trebor, i got it thank you. :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You already show that for $x=1+i$ you have
$$(x-1)^2=-1.$$
This means that $x$ is a root of
$$(X-1)^2+1=0.$$
In particular, the minimal polynomial divides this quadratic polynomial. From here it is not difficult to conclude that this *is* the minimal polynomial.

Answer (score 0):

The conjugate of $1 + i$ is $1 - i$, so try:

$\begin{align*}
  (x - (1 + i)) (x - (1 - i))
    &= x^2 - 2 x + 2
\end{align*}$

No linear polynomial over $\mathbb{Q}$ can have complex zeros, this is minimal.